# How to build recursive slices of structs in Go?

Tags: json, go, recursion, struct, slice

I need to create a JSON payload from a slice of strings. They represent the path to an individual file. They need to be merged together into final JSON payload representing the whole directory structure.

#### If the strings are below:

```
[
    "alpha/file1.json"
    "alpha/beta/file2.json"
    "alpha/beta/charlie/file3.json"
    "alpha/beta/charlie/file4.json"
    "delta/file5.json
]
```

#### JSON Payload Structure

- A Directory struct should include a name, with either Children and/or Files.
- Children will represent another Directory struct with it's own files
- Files represents the file(s) inside the Directory

#### The JSON payload would be this:

```
[{
    "Name": "alpha",
    "Files": [{
        "Name": "file1.json",
        "Path": "alpha/file1.json"
    }],
    "Children": [{
        "Name": "beta",
        "Files": [{
            "Name": "file2.json",
            "Path": "alpha/beta/file2.json"
        }],
        "Children": [{
            "Name": "charlie",
            "Files": [{
                "Name": "file3.json",
                "Path": "alpha/beta/charlie/file3.json"
            },
            {
                "Name": "file4.json",
                "Path": "alpha/beta/charlie/file4.json"
            }]
        }]
    }]
},{
    "Name": "delta",
    "Files": [
        {
            "Name": "file5.json",
            "Path": "delta/file5.json"
        }
    ]
}]
```

I can't figure out how to look to determine if the directory name already exists and pass the pointer to that directory if it does. Currently, it appends a new directory structure to the base slice for each file path. Below is what I've got so far.

https://play.golang.org/p/WoNEcJLe51z

Answer (score 0):

I needed to create a function which would return the index of the existing folder in the slice. Then recurse its Children.

```
// DirectoryStructure stores the directory structure
type DirectoryStructure struct {
    Name     string               `json:"Name"`
    Children []DirectoryStructure `json:"Children,omitempty"`
    Files    []File               `json:"Files,omitempty"`
}

// File stores the name of file and path to file
type File struct {
    Name string `json:"Name"`
    Path string `json:"Path"`
}

func main() {
    // Build slice of strings
    filePaths := []string{}
    filePaths = append(filePaths, "alpha/file1.json")
    filePaths = append(filePaths, "alpha/beta/file2.json")
    filePaths = append(filePaths, "alpha/beta/charlie/file3.json")
    filePaths = append(filePaths, "alpha/beta/charlie/file4.json")
    filePaths = append(filePaths, "delta/file5.json")

    // Create directory with slice of structs
    directory := []DirectoryStructure{}

    // Iterate through slice
    for _, path := range filePaths {
        pathSlice := strings.Split(path, "/")
        // Start recursive function. Passing directory and assigning it to itself
        directory = buildDirectory(pathSlice, path, directory)
    }

    b, err := json.Marshal(directory)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(string(b))
}

func buildDirectory(path []string, key string, directory []DirectoryStructure) []DirectoryStructure {
    // Return index of folder if it already exists.
    folderIndex := doesExist(path[0], directory)
    // If folder exists and the next value in the path slice is not the file
    if folderIndex > -1 && len(path) != 2 {
        // Pass existing folder's Children to buildDirectory function and assign to itself
        directory[folderIndex].Children = buildDirectory(path[1:], key, directory[folderIndex].Children)
        return directory
    }
    // If next value in the path slice is a file
    if len(path) == 2 {
        // If folder does not exist
        if folderIndex == -1 {
            // Create new folder with files inside and append to directory
            fileDirectory := DirectoryStructure{}
            fileDirectory.Files = []File{{path[1], string(key)}}
            fileDirectory.Name = path[0]
            directory = append(directory, fileDirectory)
        } else {
            // If folder does exist, append files to the directory
            directory[folderIndex].Files = append(directory[folderIndex].Files, File{path[1], string(key)})
        }
        return directory
    }
    // Folder does not exist and the next value is not a file
    // Create new directory, recurse it's Children, and append when returned
    currentDirectory := DirectoryStructure{}
    currentDirectory.Name = path[0]
    currentDirectory.Children = buildDirectory(path[1:], key, []DirectoryStructure{})
    directory = append(directory, currentDirectory)
    return directory

}

// doesExist returns index of folder if exists
func doesExist(folderName string, directory []DirectoryStructure) int {
    for index, element := range directory {
        if folderName == element.Name {
            return index
        }
    }
    return -1
}
```